# Why sometimes a child thread resumes before removed from waiting queue by sem_post() while sometimes it does wait for that?

Tags: c++, multithreading, semaphore

I am doing a homework relating to using multiple threads to do parallel quick sort, and I didn't hand in this homework on time due to the following difficulty. However, I still want to figure out the problem.

Basically, I am trying to assign works to child threads and control when they should begin to work by sem_post their exclusive semaphore with initial value 0 (of course, the children sem_wait their 0-value semaphores at first).

Yet, sometimes the thread 2 or 3 (I create 14 child threads) wakes up before thread 0 sem_post the semaphores which first sem_wait by them while sometimes they work as what I thought they suppose to do (wake up after removing from waiting queue by sem_post from the appointed thread).

(edited) Detailed description of what each thread is doing:

Mother thread creates 14 child threads and 14 semaphores valued 0. Each thread has their own dedicated semaphore which can be referenced by the index passed to the thread as parameter (I know it's complicated, but I don't know how to do it concisely then). At first, all child threads sem_wait their own semaphore to wait for works to do.
  Next, mother thread partitions input array as subArray1 and subArray2 by means of quick sort where subArray1 < pivot < subArray2, and then sem_post thread 0 and thread 1. At this time, mother calls sem_wait to wait for completion of the remaining sorting. 
  Thread 0 and thread 1 then do the same thing as mother thread and sem_post thread 2, 3, 4, and 5, and so on. Until the forth level, the thread 6 ~ the thread 13 will do bubble sort and sem_post mother thread to inform the completion of sorting at the end.

Below is the main part of the program：

```
typedef struct thread_param th_param;
struct thread_param {
    int index;
    int front, rear;
};
sem_t* sem[14];
sem_t* finish;
int cnt = 0;
th_param th[14];
vector<int> arr;

void *run_thread(void *index) {
pthread_detach(pthread_self());
int ind = reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(index);
if(sem_wait(sem[ind]) < 0){ /* <- the thread should wait at here for the appointed thread 
calls sem_post toward their semaphore for removing them from waiting queue */
    perror("sem_wait");
}
int front = th[ind].front;
int rear = th[ind].rear;
if(front > rear) {
    front = rear;
}
int size = rear - front + 1;
int prefix = front;
int pivot = front;
if(ind <= 5 && rear > front) {
    pivot = (rand_r(&seed) % size) + front;
    iter_swap(arr.begin()+pivot, arr.begin()+rear);
    for(int i=front; i<rear; i++) {
        if(arr[i] < arr[rear]) {
            iter_swap(arr.begin()+i, arr.begin()+prefix);
            prefix++;
        }
    }
    iter_swap(arr.begin()+prefix, arr.begin()+rear);
}
switch(ind) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
        do {
                th[(ind+1)*2].front = front;
                if(prefix > front) {
                    th[(ind+1)*2].rear = prefix-1;
                }else {
                    th[(ind+1)*2].rear = prefix;
                }
                if(prefix < rear) {
                    th[(ind+1)*2+1].front = prefix+1;
                }else {
                    th[(ind+1)*2+1].front = prefix;
                }
                th[(ind+1)*2+1].rear = rear;
        }while((th[(ind+1)*2].rear < -1) || (th[(ind+1)*2].front < -1) || (th[(ind+1)*2+1].rear < -1) || (th[(ind+1)*2+1].front < -1));
        /* thread 0/1 wakes 2,3/4,5 up respectively */
        sem_post(sem[(ind+1)*2]); 
        sem_post(sem[(ind+1)*2+1]);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
        break;
    case 2:
        do{
                th[ind*3].front = front;
                if(prefix > front) {
                    th[ind*3].rear = prefix-1;
                }else {
                    th[ind*3].rear = prefix;
                }
                if(prefix < rear) {
                    th[ind*3+1].front = prefix+1;
                }else {
                    th[ind*3+1].front = prefix;
                }
                th[ind*3+1].rear = rear;
        }while(th[ind*3].rear < -1 || th[ind*3+1].rear < -1);
        sem_post(sem[ind*3]);
        sem_post(sem[ind*3+1]);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
        break;
    case 3:
        do {
                th[ind*2+2].front = front;
                if(prefix > front) {
                    th[ind*2+2].rear = prefix-1;
                }else {
                    th[ind*2+2].rear = prefix;
                }
                if(prefix < rear) {
                    th[ind*3].front = prefix+1;
                }else {
                    th[ind*3].front = prefix;
                }
                th[ind*3].rear = rear;
        }while(th[ind*2+2].rear < -1 || th[ind*3].rear < -1);
        sem_post(sem[ind*2+2]);
        sem_post(sem[ind*3]);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
        break;
    case 4:
    case 5:
        do {
                th[ind*2+2].front = front;
                if(prefix > front) {
                    th[ind*2+2].rear = prefix-1;
                }else {
                    th[ind*2+2].rear = prefix;
                }
                if(prefix < rear) {
                    th[ind*2+3].front = prefix+1;
                }else {
                    th[ind*2+3].front = prefix;
                }
                th[ind*2+3].rear = rear;
        }while(th[ind*2+2].rear < -1 || th[ind*2+3].rear < -1);
        sem_post(sem[ind*2+2]);
        sem_post(sem[ind*2+3]);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
        break;
    default: /* bubble sort for bottom level */
        if(rear > front) {
            int temp = 0;
            for(int i=front; i<rear; i++) {
                for(int j=front; j<rear-temp; j++) {
                    if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
                        iter_swap(arr.begin()+j, arr.begin()+j+1);
                    }
                }
                temp++;
            }
        }
        cnt++;
        if(cnt == 8) {
            sem_post(finish);
        }
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}
}

void multiThread::multi_thread() {
pthread_t tid[14];
int value = 0;
int rc;
/* create and initilize semaphores */
finish = sem_open("./my_sem", O_CREAT, 0666, value);
if(finish == SEM_FAILED) {
    perror("sem_open: ");
    exit(1);
}
for(int i=0; i<14; i++) {
    sem[i] = sem_open("./my_sem", O_CREAT, 0666, value);
    if(sem[i] == SEM_FAILED) {
        perror("sem_open: ");
        exit(1);
    }
}
/* create and initialize threads */
for(int i=0; i<14; i++) {
    th[i].index = i;
    th[i].front = INT_MIN;
    th[i].rear = INT_MIN;
    rc = pthread_create(tid+i, NULL, run_thread, (void *) i);
    if(rc != 0) {
        perror("pthread_create: ");
        exit(1);
    }
}
/* first partition of quick sort */
int size = (int) arr.size();
int pivot = rand_r(&seed) % size;
int prefix = 0;
iter_swap(arr.begin()+pivot, arr.begin()+(size-1));
for(int i=0; i<(size-1); i++) {
    if(arr[i] < arr[size-1]) {
        iter_swap(arr.begin()+i, arr.begin()+prefix);
        prefix++;
    }
}
iter_swap(arr.begin()+prefix, arr.begin()+(size-1));
/* assign subarrays to threads */
th[0].front = 0;
if(prefix > 0) {
    th[0].rear = prefix-1;
} else {
    th[0].rear = prefix;
}
if(prefix < size-1) {
    th[1].front = prefix+1;
}else {
    th[1].front = prefix;
}
th[1].rear = size-1;
sem_post(sem[0]);
sem_post(sem[1]);
sem_wait(finish);
for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;
/* close semaphores and unlink path */
for(int i=0; i<14; i++) {
    rc = sem_close(sem[i]);
    if(rc != 0 ) {
        perror("sem_close(): ");
    }
}
rc = sem_close(finish);
if(rc != 0 ) {
    perror("sem_close(): ");
}
rc = sem_unlink("./my_sem");
if(rc != 0) {
    perror("sem_unlink: ");
}
}
```

This is my first time asking question on stackoverflow. If there is any suggestion to me, feel free to comment on my question. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: C != C++. Tag only with the language that you're using, unless both are actually relevant.

Comment: Yes - this is obviously C++

Comment: This implementation of a parallel quicksort is umm.. very complex.  I understand that the hell-inspired design of putting thread parameters etc. into arrays and directly referring to threads by means of indexes is deeply embedded into textbooks and courses, but I wish it would stop.  It makes everything very messy, inflexible and error-prone:(   An overall description of the algorithm used, (some unholy combo of quicksort and bubble sort?), and, if you must design like that, what each thread is doing, may have cleared things up a bit:)

Comment: So is "sem_wait" printed? put a break point there.

Comment: @MartinJames I've added detailed description, thank you for your advice.   As for the way on binding threads with semaphores, I know what you mean, but  neither the professor nor the TA (or even classmates) would do code review for me. So, though I know that I should improve the way I write code, I don't know how to get better in this situation. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Surt Sorry, what do you mean by printing sem_wait? I've tested whether sem_wait indeed block thread 2, the answer is yes. Yet, I have no idea why thread 2 (and sometimes thread 3) woke up in the wrong way (didn't wake up by sem_post called by thread 0) when all other threads using the same code work just fine...

Comment: @WayneChen, you have a perror("sem_wait") does it ever activate, to check put a break point in your debugger. I was wondering some of the other possible causes of sem_wait failing, certain signals fired also wakes the sem_wait according to the manual.

Comment: @Surt No, the perror("sem_wait") never activate. I'm not sure why putting a break point on that line? Since if sem_wait fails, it will print the error message automatically.

Comment: Hi guys, I finally found the bug...I should use a different path name each time when sem_open a new semaphore. Otherwise, it will just return the existent semaphore address back to the sem_t* variable, which is not a new semaphore.